# Twig translation concatenate

Tags: symfony, twig, concatenation, translation

I want to translate a variable that contains a string plus a variable like the next one:

```
  {{ 'string' ~ variable|trans }}
```

It seems that it's only taking the variable to translate without the string part.

I just discovered it that I can fix this problem creating a previous variable that contains the concatenation from the string and the previous variable like the next example:

```
   {% set X = 'string' ~ variable %}
```

And now we are able to translate what we were trying to translate just translating the X variable:

```
   {{ X|trans }}
```

I tried to translate this concatenation like this:

```
   {% trans %} {{'string' ~ variable }} {% endtrans %}
```

But also was not a succesfull result for me.

Is any other way to avoid creating this "x" varible to be able to translate all the concatenation straight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
{{ ('string'~variable)|trans }}
```

Positioning of the braces is important here otherwise filters always will be handled before the concatenation.

Comment: Is not working this solution. Did you tried? It's just taking the variable.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my application yes.

Comment: I couldn't see the rounded brackets srry... XD Thank you so much